# Implementing Hierarchical Attention for Classification

Tags: neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network, pytorch, attention-model

I am trying to implement the Hierarchical Attention [paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~diyiy/docs/naacl16.pdf) for text classification. One of the challenges that I am finding is how to manage batching and updates to the weights of the network by the optimizer.  The architecture of the network is made of two encoders stacked one after the other: a sentence encoder, and a document encoder.

When the dataset is made of large documents, the following problem arises: for each pass through the document encoder, you will have multiple passes through the sentence encoder.  When the loss is calculated and the optimizer uses the calculated gradients to update the weights of the parameters of the network, I am assuming that the weights of the sentence encoder should be updated differently to the weights of the document encoder.  What is a good strategy to do so? How could that strategy could be implemented in libraries such as `Keras` or `Pytorch`?